# Best way to crop a RAW image file to TIFF preserving quality

Tags: images, conversion

I am a nature photographer, and it is usual that I take a picture with the subject in a small portion of the picture. Now I am doing astrophotography and face the same situation, with a small Saturn in the vast space of my featureless black image.

Since my disks already have hundred of thousands of pictures and TBs of data, the management is becoming a bit resource intensive. So I usually want to save only a small crop of these RAW files semi-automatically. I've done this with `rawtherapee` and a custom profile that essentially does nothing but demosaicing, cropping, and saving a 16 bit TIFF.

I am looking for a better way to do this, from the command line only, since I do not trust rawtherapee to modify my RAWs in a permanent way. I've found some articles in Google, but they are old, and probably by now there are better tools.

So, what I want is:

1. Crop the RAW file content and save it into a 16 BIT TIFF as losslessly as possible (demosaiced or not? Linear?)
2. Preserve all Metadata.
3. Ensure the use of the files for many years.

I can certainly do this to some extent with a combination of `ufraw`, `convert`, `mogrify` or `exiftool`, etc, but I am not sure which is a really good way. For example:

```
 ufraw-batch --interpolation=ahd --base-curve=camera --out-type=tif --out-depth=16 --exif --crop-top=1904 --crop-left=2304 --crop-right=2784 --crop-bottom=2336 --wb=auto --overwrite input.orf --output=output.tif
```

Yes, I know that `--wb=auto` or `--base-curve=camera` are not losslessly, but that is ok I think. Also, I think I don't want to demosaic the image, since I don't like the AHD algorithm (AMAZE seems to get more detail out of the ORF files).

Moreover, after the conversion, `identify` tells me that the metadata of output.tif has problems:

```
identify: Invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectoryCheckOrder' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/983.
```

`identify` in the original file gave no errors. How to trust `ufraw` then?

Comment: I guess the question would be a lot more readable if the main question (as I understand it) would be at the beginning of the question, not at the end.

Comment: The main question is in the title, not at the end.